# Retrieve children from self-referencing entity with certain condition in Doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have an entity `Post` and it has, among others, the properties `parent`, `children` and `published`. The property `parent` is a manyToOne relationship and `children` a oneToMany relationship to itself. The `published` property is a boolean.

I want to get a `Post` with a certain ID, with the children that are published, so have `published` set to true.

I want to achieve this with the QueryBuilder or in DQL. I tried the following, but it still returned the not-published children as well.

```
    $dql = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
        SELECT
            p
        FROM
            SomeBundle\Entity\Post p
        LEFT JOIN
            p.children pc WITH pc.published = :published
        WHERE
            p.id = :id
    ');

    $dql->setParameters(array(
        'id' => $id,
        'published' => true
    ));
```

Comment: I don't think you should/want to do this. If for any reason you would persist the incomplete `Post`, all not-loaded children would be deleted from the collection. The better approach would be to simply *ask* the post repository to give you *a list of published children by a given parent*. Use this list then independently of the parent post.

Comment: After some testing, I'm no longer sure the *incomplete collection* would actually result in any deletion. Though, as doctrine holds an identity map of all loaded entities, if you issue the above query, and later try to load the same post differently with all children, the latter collection would still be incomplete (meaning the collection would not be refreshed). If all that is acceptable, you can try changing your query to `SELECT p, pc FROM ...`, this way the relation should be populated as desired (though you might need to move `pc.published = :published` to the *where* part of the query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine SQL Filters are your friend.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Example:
Put a class in your project (for example in filters)

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Filter\SQLFilter;

class PublishedFilter extends SQLFilter
{

/**
 * @param ClassMetadata $targetEntity
 * @param string        $targetTableAlias
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
{
    if (!array_search('published', $targetEntity->getFieldNames())) {
        return '';
    }

    return $targetTableAlias.'.published = true';

}
}
```

Now you just need to add that filter in your doctrine config (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html). Tadaaaa.wav

Important to know is that if you need to select the filtered stuff (for example in the backend), you need to disable the filter
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getFilters()->disable('published');

edit: to explain a bit what it does
It adds the (in your example) p.published = true condition into every query if your schema actually has the "published" field.

Comment: Does this really help? It's basically the same as doing it *by hand* just way more complex and hidden. And it would also not deal with the problem of an incomplete collection.

Comment: @yoshi Yes. it will only return the ones that are publshed as long as there is a "published" boolean field. Also if you want to save collections, you just deactivate the filter when you handle the collection in the action. Maybe it's a bit complex but you will never have to worry about the published thing again if you want to display stuff.